# How to extract absolute URL of href with relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to extract download links from this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/install/index.html).

Here is the page source (viewing in Google Chrome) of that link:

[image]

When I point at `../matlab/licensing.pdf` on the page source, a link `https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/licensing.pdf` appears.

I inspect `../matlab/licensing.pdf` but the link does not appear on the right hand. Thus I am unable to extract this link with regrex in Python.

Please help me extract this link from the page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)

example:

```py
import urllib.parse

base = r"https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/install/index.html"
link_in_html = r"../matlab/licensing.pdf"

result = urllib.parse.urljoin(base, link_in_html)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! I works perfectly fine. I would like to ask if the absolute url (the link that I want to extract) is contained in the page source.

Comment: @LeAnhDung you can achieve that by a regular sub-string check on the page content. I suspect it won't be contained though, using relative paths is actually a good practice.